# File compression in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.Net application I want to compress a file and send it to the user, but the classes which are available compress files which are less than 4 to 5 GB. But through my application i want to compress a file which is more then 5 GB.
Is there any way to do that ?

Thank You.

Comment: Would you want to stream it while compressing or compress then send?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? Which Visual Studio?

Comment: To my knowledge this is the problem with the Visual Studio version.IF you are using Express edition,then it has got size limits.Check out n reply.

Answer (score 1):

does this help ? http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=730

Answer (score 0):

SharpZipLib is usually the choice for file compression in dot-net.
http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/

I used it in my projects; its pretty fast and very easy to work with.